# Can not connect to Pushshift.io despite correctly creating reddit praw instance

Tags: python, reddit

I followed the instruction on how to connect to pushshift in the psaw documentation but it doesn't seem to be working. An example of how you are able to use pushshift would be useful.

When I run the following code:

```
from psaw import PushshiftAPI
import praw
reddit_ = praw.Reddit(client_id='something', client_secret='something', user_agent='something')
api = PushshiftAPI(reddit_)
```

I get the following error:
"Unable to connect to pushshift.io. Retrying after backoff."

I believe I created the praw reddit instance properly so I do not know what the error is.